# How to import date-fns from node_modules in frontend file when 'type: module' is defined in package.json?

Tags: javascript, npm, es6-modules, date-fns

Previously, in an application where `type:module` was *not* specified in its `package.json`,

I could do this in a frontend JavaScript file:

```js
import {
  getYear,
  getMonth,
  getDaysInMonth,
  startOfMonth,
  getDay,
  format,
  parseISO,
} from 'date-fns';
```

Now, in an application where `type:module` *is* specified in its `package.json`, the above import statement returns:

> Uncaught TypeError:
> Failed to resolve module specifier "date-fns". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I understand that if I were importing my own module in this environment, I would have to specify the exact filename.

However, when I try this:

```js
import parseISO from '../../../node_modules/date-fns/parseISO/index.js';
```

I get this error in chrome developer tools console:

> GET http://localhost:3000/node_modules/date-fns/parseISO/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

The version of date-fns that is listed as a dependency in my `package.json` is:

```
"date-fns": "^2.29.3",
```

How do I import date-fns (and its various 'sub-packages') from `node_modules` in a frontend file when `type: module` is defined in `package.json`?

This scenario is not mentioned in the installation docs, so I must be missing something very obvious / basic:

https://date-fns.org/v2.29.3/docs/Getting-Started

(Also, in case it is relevant, I was using webpack in the previous application, but not in the new application, so perhaps that is the reason the original import statement worked in the previous application?)

Comment: Did you stumble into an answer? I'm really stumped here with the very same issue in the very same lib.